<TouchableWithoutFeedback /> is blocking the scroll
I have a case where I need to use <TouchableWithoutFeedback /> as a global wrapper for some close dropdown events and it works fine for that. But this has raised another issue which doesn't allow scroll events to happen because the onPress triggering. So <ScrollView /> is blocked. Interesting when I click the inputs and scroll, it works fine.
So I don't know what to do, Its a must for me to do that so I can close the dropdowns. But also this break one critical feature too.
Here is the page layout that applies on everypage:
import type { FC, ReactNode } from 'react'
import type { NormalLayoutProps } from '@/ts'

import { SafeAreaView, TouchableWithoutFeedback, GestureResponderEvent } from 'react-native'
import { tw } from '@/libs'

const PageLayout: FC<NormalLayoutProps> = (props): ReactNode => {
    const { children, onOutsideClick } = props

    const handlePress = (e: GestureResponderEvent) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        e.preventDefault()
        onOutsideClick?.()
    }

    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handlePress} style={tw`w-full h-full bg-[#EFF4F6]`}>
            <SafeAreaView>
                {children}
            </SafeAreaView>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}

export default PageLayout

What do you recommend?

try to add flex: 1 to SafeAreaView

I think it will be better to make your dropdown position absolute and add a temporary mask over your page and beneath the dropdown to handle those close events instead of nesting them, as you have noticed there will be conflict when nesting Touchable and ScrollView.
If you want to keep the nesting structure , you can use react-native-gesture-handler to solve the conflict. e.g.
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import { ScrollView, GestureDetector, Gesture, GestureHandlerRootView  } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

export default function App() {
    const tap = Gesture.tap().onStart(()=>{
        // on touched callback
    })

    return <GestureHandlerRootView>
        <GestureDetector gesture={tap}>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <ScrollView>
                    //items
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </GestureDetector>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
}

